# Inject Hibernate sessionfactory in a Grails service

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am struggling with using [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) simply for saving a user in [Grails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_%28framework%29), nothing else. I could not find any example/tutorial for this one.

I am not looking for GORM, scaffolding, etc. WI am trying to use `sessionFactory` in my service to persist a `UserEntity`.

```
        def sessionFactory
        def hibSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setEmail("grails")
        hibSession.save(userEntity);
        hibSession.flush()
```

But it says sessionFactory is null.

It is not clear to me how to access `sessionfactory` in my service.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2**: Create an integration test to verify that sessionFactory is injected properly. Run the following grails command:

`create-integration-test <package>.MyService`

You may have to delete the unit test file `MyServiceSpec.groovy` in the test/unit directory if it exists.

Implement the following Test:

```
    class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def myService

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        when:
        def u = myService.serviceMethod()

        then:
        u != null

    }
}
```

You also need to change your service method to return the user instance to make the test work as I did below.

Run `test-app <package.MyService -integration`

Does this test pass? If not, please provide further information about your development environment.

**Edit**: This probably doesn't matter in this case, but what is your grails version/development environment? It is better to specify that when asking a question.

Firstly, why are you not using GORM? I don't see many benefits from using grails without using it's core features. Why do you want to use `sessionFactory` to manage the ORM instead of GORM? GORM does the same under the hood if you just call `new UserEntity(email:'grails').save()`.

This leads me to my next point: you are not using  the features of Groovy either. In Groovy, you can use map constructors like I did above and also use setter methods like that: `user.email = 'grails'.`

Furthermore, after a service method is called, the session is flushed automatically, so you don't need to flush it manually. This only applies, however, if the service method is transactional -- and they are by default.

I don't want to discourage you from using Grails, but IMHO you don't leverage the powerful tools of Groovy and Grails and rather code Java, Spring and Hibernate. You only make use of the conventions, such as Domain Classes, Controllers, Views and Services, and I don't know if that is worth it. But it is your choice, your approach surprises me to say the least.

Secondly, this is the way your code works:

MyService.groovy:

```
@Transactional
class MyService {

    def sessionFactory

    UserEntity serviceMethod() {
        def s = sessionFactory.currentSession
        def u = new UserEntity(email:'grails')
        s.save(u)
        //or: 
        //def user = new UserEntity()
        //user.email = 'grails'
        //s.save(user)
        //or do it the Java way like in your code 

        u.id ? u : null                
    }
}
```

`sessionFactory` needs to be declared as a field in your service so that spring can inject it by naming convention at startup. Judging from your code, you should do some further reading on spring and dependency injection. 
You could have a look at [the official Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) or, to learn it by doing step by step first, at [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_dependency_injection.htm).`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer , 
Actually i am using GWT as a front end in my grails framework
I  went through the GORM , but the way it was being used was generating views automatically groovy pages etc ,atleast in the tutorials i found , and i already have GWT views in which i need to send some data from db, so i tried doing hibernate for now.

I used ur code above, but it says 'sessionFactory'  is null.

Please guide me why my sessionFactory is null, do i need to define it somewhere else ,or i am missing anything..

thanks

Comment: What is your Grails Version? How do you test your service code? I will include a sample integration test in my answer. In unit tests, beans are not autowired.